# Getting point coordinates in Matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, spyder

I'm using Ipython interpreter in Spyder environment.
I would like to write a script to crop all the images in a folder at the same dimension. 
I plot the *.jpg image using Matplotlib. I would like to be able to use the mouse to point two corners on the picture that would correspond to the top-left and bottom-right of the new picture.

I have written a code like that

```
import os
import scipy.ndimage as nd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close('all')

class Conoscopia:
    def __init__(self, cono, nome):
        self.x1 = 0.0
        self.y1 = 0.0
        self.x2 = 0.0
        self.y2 = 0.0
        self.cono = cono
        self.nome = nome

    def connect(self):
        self.cid = self.cono.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onclick)

    def onclick(self, event):
        if self.x1==0.0 and self.y1==0.0:
            self.x1=event.xdata
            self.y1=event.ydata
            print "x1 = ", event.xdata, " y1 = ", event.xdata
        elif self.x2==0.0 and self.y2==0.0:
            self.x2=event.xdata
            self.y2=event.ydata
            print "x2 = ", event.xdata, " y2 = ", event.xdata     

    def return_coo(self):
        return self.x1, self.x2, self.y1, self.y2

    def disegna(self):
        plt.imshow(self.nome)
        plt.show()       

plt.ioff()

files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

lista_nomi=[]
for nome in files:
    if nome[len(nome)-4:len(nome)] == '.JPG' or nome[len(nome)-4:len(nome)] == '.jpg':
        lista_nomi.append(nome)

foto = nd.imread(lista_nomi[0])

id_f = plt.figure()

cn = Conoscopia(id_f, foto)
cn.connect()
cn.disegna()

x1, y1, x2, y2 = cn.return_coo()
```

My problem is that the whole code is run at once and that at the end the values of x1, y1, x2 and y2 correspond to the intialization values.
I can then click on the picture to get the four values and if I run in the interpreter `x1, y1, x2, y2 = cn.return_coo()` they contain the right values.
But what can I do to retrieve them directly in my code and being able to use them?
What I would ideally like is that once that the two clicks are done, the window close and that I can use the coordinates (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) for the rest of my programming.

I have tried to add some extra waiting loop or looping on the function `return_coo()` until the coordinates are different from the initialization values but this block my computer and I never get the pricture displayed.

Thanks!

Comment: I realized that the problem exists only with an Ipython interprter. With a "normal" Python interpreter everything run fine.

Comment: In your `onclick` method, after you set the second co-ordinate, can you just call whatever code you want to happen next?

Comment: You want a closure, but I don't quite understand what is wrong with the way you are doing it.  As a side note, it would be better to use `np.nan` or `None` to represent 'no data', rather than `0.0` and rely on float comparison.

Comment: In fact with the Iphython interpreter the rest of the code is executed directly before I close the graphic window. It is like matplotlib stays interactive even if I ask the interactive mode to be off. On a "normal" Python interpreter everything works fine, I put the interactive mode off and the rest of the code is executed only when the graphic window is closed.

Comment: This @AlessandroBenedetto - can you provide a little more detail on what the outstanding question is? Thanks!

Comment: The problem was that by using IPython the interpreter does not wait that the graphic windows is closed before executing the rest of the code and thus the value of the clicked coordinates can not be used.